# Precise delays on Arduino using nop assembly?

Tags: c, assembly, arduino, arduino-uno

I'm looking to make a very short pulse after a rising edge signal input.

The hard part here is that I would like to control (to high resolution) the timing of the delay before my pulse, and the duration of my pulse. I can easily control this by just stringing together nops by myself, hard coding delays, but I'm not sure how to do it for some arbitrary delay, with the same level of accuracy.

After a lot of headaches chasing down timers, and then eventually realizing I am ultimately limited by the interrupt routine entry/exit time, I am now settling at trying to control my delay via nops.

I had assumed this C switch statement would be what I wanted (after compiling, hoping it would become efficient and just change the program counter to the right spot), but it produces some very odd behavior...

```
  switch(delayTime){
    case 10:
      __asm__ __volatile__("nop");
    case 9:
      __asm__ __volatile__("nop");
    case 8:
      __asm__ __volatile__("nop");
    case 7:
      __asm__ __volatile__("nop");
    case 6:
      __asm__ __volatile__("nop");
    case 5:
      __asm__ __volatile__("nop");
    case 4:
      __asm__ __volatile__("nop");
    case 3:
      __asm__ __volatile__("nop");
    case 2:
      __asm__ __volatile__("nop");
    case 1:
      __asm__ __volatile__("nop");
  }
  PORTD = 0x10;
 ...
```

Ideally, I would like to essentially run through some code that would compile into this: (it's some weird pseudocode of C and assembly, still not sure how to do some of it in assembly)

```
0x005 Reg1 = 0xFF-val1      %(where somehow 0xFF is known? / found out?)
0x006 Reg2 =0x1FF-val2
0x007 IJMP Reg1
0x008 NOP
0x009 NOP
0x00A NOP
...
0x0FF MOV 0x40, PORTD  % assign the value 0x40 to the static variable "PORTD"
0x100 IJMP Reg2
0x101 NOP
0x102 NOP
0x103 NOP
0x104 NOP
...
0x1FF MOV 0x00, PORTD   % assign the value 0x00 to the static variable "PORTD"
```

I'm just overall not sure how to find the memory location for the code after/during run time so that the "0xFF" and "0x1FF" aspects of this program are not really so bad (it seems like it's super dangerous to just, get the assembly of the code, and then hard code that in... I'd rather not do that).  Also, while it's easy to just flood it with the 200+ nops, how to get the IJMP cmd to behave the way I want it to? (I honestly don't even know if that's the command I want)..

I guess in general I'm looking for some assembly command (that I can't seem to find) that allows me to "add N to Program Counter"   and I can just make sure that that command is run in assembly with at least N+1 commands of assembly ahead of it, hardcoded in.

As a side note, all of this is executing inside of an interrupt routine, so I don't feel so bad about playing around with the PC... Also, I know is kinda bad blocking for up to 500 operations, but for the task at hand, timing is more important than how badly it blocks as a routine.

Comment: What's wrong with the delay routines in AVR Libc?

Comment: In order to get the precision I want, I think I need to use something like "__builtin_avr_delay_cycles"  However, this function requires a constant (it's a macro that seems to be built at compile time) while I am instead looking for some function that I can call with a variable at run time. As far as I can tell, just moving the PC in memory to get the exact number of nops is the most reliable solution, but its possible I missed something in the AVR libc. (I only see ways to make 3,4 cycles per iteration) which isn't enough time resolution for what I want out of this 16 MHz clock.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the AVR instruction set, but the general idea is to use the `CALL` instruction to put the program counter (PC) on the stack. Then use `POP` to move the PC to the Z register.  Then you can `ADD` some number to the Z register, and use `IJMP` to jump to the resulting address.

So something along these lines

```
delay:  call delay1             ; push the PC onto the stack
delay1: pop  r30                ; pop the PC into the Z registers
        pop  r31
        add  r30,r0             ; add some amount to the PC value
        addc r31,r1
        ijmp                    ; use IJMP to jump to the resulting address
        nop
        nop
        nop
        ...
```

Random thoughts:

- On the 8MB machines, you need a third pop to remove the third byte of
  the PC from the stack.
- Z is only sixteen bits, therefore this code must be in the first
  128KB of program memory.
- I'm not sure which register (r30 or r31) is supposed to be popped
  first.
- The value added to Z must be relative to `delay1` since `call` is
  going to push the address of `delay1` onto the stack. In other words,
  the minimum amount that needs to be added is 6, since that's the
  number of instructions from `delay1` to the first `nop`.
- The minimum delay is determined by the six instructions up to and
  including the `ijmp`. You should increase r1/r0 (reduce the number of
  nops) accordingly.

Like I said, I'm no expert on the AVR instruction set, so you should take this as a general suggestion, and be prepared to spend some time working out the particulars.  Good luck!